# System::TaskName In PreExecute Event Handler?

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am trying to dynamically set my SSIS Default Buffer Max Rows property by running the following query in an Execute SSIS Tasl on the PreExecute event of a Data Flow task:

```
SELECT 
    SUM (max_length)  [row_length]
FROM  sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id=c.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON t.schema_id=s.schema_id
WHERE t.name = 'TableName'
    AND s.name = 'SchemaName'
```

I am attempting to be clever and use the name of my Data Flow Task (which is the same as my Destination table name) as a parameter in my Execute SQL Task by referencing the System::TaskName variable.

The problem is, that everything seems to validate correctly but, when it comes to executing the process, the PreExecute fails.

I have since found out that this is due to System::TaskName not being available at anything other than Execute.

Are there any alternative variables / methods that I can use other than dumping a load of script tasks that manually change a variable into my flow?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer,

I have used System::SourceName

Daniel